# Meteor - Google Maps InfoWindow Event Not Firing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, meteor, infowindow

Using Meteorjs and dburles google map package for Meteor.

The Goal:
Is to have the markers map out on the canvas, and then onclick to reveal the infoWindows. I am having an issue firing the google map event in order for the window to reveal.

My Code:

```
 Template.myMap.helpers({
   mapOptions: function() {
    var locations = [
       ['Kroger', 34.069201, -84.231052, 5],
       ['Fresh Produce', 34.069802, -84.234164, 4],
       ['Starbucks', 34.069003, -84.236323, 3],
       ['Mall of Georgia', 34.069204, -84.232016, 2],
       ['Avalanche', 34.069705, -84.238207, 1]
      ]

// Make sure the maps API has loaded
if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
  // We can use the `ready` callback to interact with the map API once the map is ready.
  GoogleMaps.ready('myMap', function(map) {
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map.instance
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  return {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.069705, -84.238),
    zoom: 16
  };
}
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning a function from the event handler rather than just handling the event, for reasons that aren't clear.  Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

**UPDATE**

The other problem is that you're trying to add it to the GoogleMaps map object, not the instance itself.  It should be:

```
infowindow.open(map.instance, marker);
```

Also, I haven't run your code, but I think you're going to run into problems with the way you've structured this, as the value of `i` will not be as intended when the handler is actually fired (because the loop will have subsequently continued).  Consider using `forEach` instead (below via underscore) so that each handler is declared in its own closure.

```
  _.forEach(locations, function(location) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]),
            map: map.instance
          }); 

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(location[0]);
          console.log(map, marker, infowindow);
          infowindow.open(map.instance, marker);
      });        
  });
```

Comment: When I do that, I get this error message "cannot read property 'infowindowviewpool' of undefined". Do you have any idea? I thought the map is already being defined before it comes in the funtion, and you should only get that error if it isn't.