# How do I get multiple values by an array and display this Place in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, meteor, google-maps-markers

I'm working on a project, in Meteor based on NodeJS, I need to create "markers" (Places) on the map via Google Maps API. 
These markers are in a "list" array

```
var list = Offers.find({});

list = [
{
  place: "Teste2",
  offer: "Teste Offer2",
  loc: {
    coordinates: [-50.1681836, -25.0869446]
  }
},
{
  place: "Teste1",
  offer: "Teste Offer1",
  loc: {
    coordinates: [-40.1681836, -20.0869446]
  }
}];
```

And these respective locations must be displayed on the map, each location with its respective marker...

```
var count = 0;
list.forEach(function(offer) {
 console.log(offer);
  // Animation Timeout
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Create the string into the infowindow
    var contentString = '<p><strong>' + offer.place + '</strong></p>' +
    '<p>' + offer.offer + '</p>';

    // Create the infowindow object
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    // Add the marker on the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: offer.loc.coordinates[1], lng: offer.loc.coordinates[0]},
      map: map.instance,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    // Add the infowindow for each marker
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(contentString);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }, count * 200);

  count++;
});
```

However, just shown is only the first array position ("Teste2"), not all multiple values ​​by "list".

Comment: Is your code throwing an error ? In your marker code you're using `map.instance` while in your infowindow code you're using `map`.

Comment: No, my code isn't throwing an error.
It's working... but the app show just the first position of array 'list', and I need it display all the places in the 'list'.

Comment: Start with a [simple](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple) working example and expand it gradually with animated features.

Answer (score 1):

May be because you're using the `infowindow` variable without any declaration.

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  infowindow.setContent(contentString);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Create a infowindow object in your loop **before** setting the marker listener like this :

```
let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString
});
```

[More information in the Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple)

**EDIT**

Change also those lines

```
list.forEach(function(offer, index) {   //  <--- change for index
  console.log(offer);
  // [...]

  // Add the infowindow for each marker
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);  //  <--- remove this one
    infowindow.open(map, marker);  //  <--- map or map.instance ??
  });

  // Animation Timeout
  setTimeout(function() {
    // [...]
  }, index * 200);  //  <--- change for index
});
```

After that, you can remove all `count` references.

For `infowindow.open(map, marker)`, the `map` reference should be the same as for the marker.

What is the variable where `new google.maps.Map()` is ? `map.instance` or `map` ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!
I created the infowindow object, but it doesn't display all the places of the 'list' yet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is the `map` / `map.instance` confusion.

Comment: I change the code, like you said.
I remove all `count` references and add the `index`
And I test the app with `map` and `map.instance`
But it doesn't work!

Answear your question, There is no `new google.maps.Map()`, the map is created with this operation
`GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', function(map) {
      [...]
      map: map.instance,
    });
`

Comment: I forgot you're using meteor, my bad... So I confirm that you have to use `map.instance` for both. I found this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976207/meteor-google-maps-infowindow-event-not-firing), perhaps it will help you ? 
If not, I have many test cases for you :
1. Could you try to loop without using the `setTimeout()` function ?
2. Could you try to add markers without any infowindow code (to see if an _error_ stop the loop) ?

Comment: I created a fiddle with your code and it worked fine (without meteor). That's why I didn't make any changes on it. Good luck !

Comment: Well, I removed the `setTimeout` function and added the `markers` without the infowindows. The app keeps showing just the first place from `list`. I think the problem is the `forEach` function... I will try the solution that you sent me! I am going to write the result here soon.